# Does azure blob storage lifecycle count time or just date?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We defined data from azure blob container to be deleted after 1 day with the following policy

```json
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "name": "expirationRule",
      "enabled": true,
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [ "blockBlob" ]
        },
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "delete": { "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 1 }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

We know that platform runs the lifecycle policy once a day.
And it will delete files, but will it count hours, minutes, or just take days.

For example, I upload a file at 9:00, I will create a lifecycle at 13:00. The container will trigger lifecycle tomorrow at 13:00 and delete the file or it will be deleted the day after tomorrow after a full day?

Comment: what do you mean "the container will trigger lifecycle tomorrow at 13:00"? you create the policy at 13:00 in tomorrow, or you've already created the policy and it'll be triggered 13:00 in tomorrow?

Comment: for example, I will create it at 13:00 today and it will be triggered tomorrow at 13:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first time to run lifecycle management policy, it can take up to 24 hours to run the policy.

For example, you upload a file at `9:00 AM today`, and then create a lifecycle policy at `13:00 PM today`. The file will be deleted
within `24 hours`. It means that the file will be deleted at any time between `13:00 PM today` and `13:00 PM tomorrow`.